# Iterated Limits Along an Ultrafilter

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence, harmonic-analysis, filters

**Setting:**

---

Let $\mathfrak{U}$ be an ultrafilter on an index set $I$.

Let $G$ be a compact group with identity $e$, and let $\mathbb{T}$ denote the unit circle in the complex plane.

For each $i\in I$, let $\gamma_{i}:G\to \mathbb{T}$ be a continuous group homomorphism, and choose $s_{i},t_{i}\in G$.

---

**Question:**

---

Under what circumstances can I compute the limit

$$\displaystyle\lim_{i\to\mathfrak{U}}\gamma_{i}(s_i^{-1}t_{i})$$

iteratively, by instead considering

$$\displaystyle\lim_{i\to\mathfrak{U}}\displaystyle\lim_{j\to\mathfrak{U}}\gamma_{i}(s_j^{-1}t_{j})?$$

---

**Motivation:**

---

I can easily compute the latter limit as 1, since in my setting I have the additional assumption that $\displaystyle\lim_{j\to\mathfrak{U}}s_j^{-1}t_{j} = e$

Comment: Have you tried even a simple case?

Comment: Without being rigorous, I was able to vaguely come up with an example of sequences where this does not hold.  But I did not work it out fully.  I can do so over the next hour and report back!

Comment: Note that my question was not whether this holds in general.  I'm asking about sufficient and/or necessary conditions for these limits to agree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Does not hold in general**

A simple case...
$$
G = \mathbb T = \{z \in \mathbb C \; : \; |z|=1\},\qquad\text{with mutiplication}
\\
I = \{1,2,3,\dots\},
\\
\mathfrak U = \text{ any free ultrafilter}
\\
\gamma_n(z) = z^n
\\
s_n = 1, t_n = e^{i \pi/n}
\\
\lim_n \gamma_n(s_n^{-1}t_n) = \lim_n \big(e^{i \pi/n}\big)^n = 
\lim_n e^{i\pi} = \lim_n (-1) = -1
\\
\lim_n\lim_m \gamma_n(s_m^{-1}t_m) = \lim_n\lim_m \big(e^{i\pi/m}\big)^n
=\lim_n\big(\lim_m e^{i\pi/m}\big)^n
=\lim_n\big(1\big)^n = \lim_n 1 = 1
$$